Is it possible implement CombineLogs function in HttpLogging for net core 6?
I have set the code below on the "startup.cs".
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestBody | HttpLoggingFields.ResponseBody;
    logging.RequestBodyLogLimit = 4096;
    logging.ResponseBodyLogLimit = 4096;
});

After call the api. The log will show as below:
2024-07-23 22:19:10.5235 INFO Request:
 
2024-07-23 22:19:10.7989 INFO RequestBody: {
  "Name": "John"
} 
2024-07-23 22:19:10.8397 INFO Response:
 
2024-07-23 22:19:10.9075 INFO ResponseBody: {"Message":"Hello, John"}

I only need log the request and response body.
How to filter the Request and Response?
And I also want combine the request and response body into single line log.
It seems have CombineLogs property to do this but this property didn't exist net 6.
And for some reason I can't upgrade to net 8.
Is it possible combine the log in net 6?

for some reason I can't upgrade to net 8. what reason? .NET 6 reaches End of Support in November 2024 - just 4 months from now.

What do you mean I only need log the request and response body. ? You're already only logging the request and response bodies. The timestamp, log level etc are emitted by the logger, not the HTTP logging middleware, and are configured in the logging configuration. What you posted looks like console logging.

You can use custom middleware for this by intercepting request and response.
refer:
How do I get the incoming request body and the outgoing response body in ASP.NET Core middleware?
If you are using .Net 8 you can use IHttpLoggingInterceptor for customizing what details get logged
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttplogginginterceptor
For .Net 6 I don't see any higher customisation for IHttpLogging
